# Можно ли разработать скрипт для получения исходного кода интерпретируемой программы?

Tags: python, безопасность, шифрование

Я порылся на разных форумах, где прочитал, что исходный код программы на питоне можно зашифровать. А можно ли как-то смотреть на выполнение кода интерпретатором? Можно ли достать ключ для расшифровки в исходный код, и где этот самый ключ находится? Можно ли написать программу, которая сможет смотреть на работу интерпретатора и в результате выводить исходный код исполняемой программы?

Comment: Все зависит от того, что там за шифрование. Откуда нам знать, что там на тех форумах написано.

Comment: Чтобы запустить программу нужно же все равно расшифровать исходный код. И можно ли где то перехватить этот расшифрованный код? Это и будет исходником

Comment: Чтобы запустить программу, достаточно байткода в принципе. По байткоду теоретически можно восстановить исходный код. Но в целом это все рассуждения "кто-то где-то сказал".

Comment: Можно исходный код транслировать на язык Си (см. nuitka, prometeo), скомпилировать в exe, потом еще поверх зашифровать. Даже расшифрованный exe вам ничего не даст, исходный код на Python вы из него не получите. Все очень зависит от конкретного процесса. В некоторых случаях теоретически можно как-то Python код получить, в некоторых - нет.

Comment: Мне именно интересно можно ли добыть исходник какой-то программы на питоне, если разраб зашифровал этот исходник? Из интернета мы скачиваем программу в которой исходник зашифрован. Но ведь чтобы перевести питоновский код в байткод спец библиотеки сначала должны расшифровать все загогулины в код, который будет понятен интерпретатору.  И меня интересует можно ли во время расшифровки вытянуть этот код? Или достать исходный код во время работы интерпретатора?

Comment: Еще раз: зависит от конкретного процесса. Об абстрактном случае в вакууме рассуждать бессмысленно.

Comment: Исходный код на любом языке можно зашифровать. Смотреть на выполнение кода можно отладчиком. Чтобы зашифрованный код попал в выполнение, он должен быть предварительно расшифрован обратно. Вы, возможно, путаете шифрование с обфускацией.

Comment: @ushiYT-майнкрафт есть зашифрованный код? добавьте либо в вопрос либо через ссылку.